# How is the version number in library_names generated?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, ld, libtool

While compiling most of the opensource libraries, make command generates `.la` file, which will have `library_names` and `current=11 age=9 revision=0` version information.

I understand that version information `current=11 age=9 revision=0` is generated from the flag `version-info` in **Makefile.am**. By just knowing the version information, how does `make` generate library names?

Example : For [libcrack.so](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/cracklib.html)

```
dlname='libcrack.so.2'
# Names of this library.
library_names='libcrack.so.2.9.0 libcrack.so.2 libcrack.so'

# Version information for libcrack.
current=11
age=9
revision=0
```

version info is specified in Makefile.am as follows

```
libcrack_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info 11:0:9
```

Now the question is: How does make generate `libcrack.so.2.9.0` with the number `2.9.0` by just taking `version-info`?

Answer (score 2):

Usually `libtool` library version system uses the following format

`soname.so.<current-age>.<age>.<revision>`

That is why in example quoted in the question, `libcrack.so.(11-9).9.0 = libcrack.2.9.0`.

More detailed information can be found at [library versioning](https://autotools.io/libtool/version.html)